# Is there a quantum algorithm for the closest vector problem on a 2-dimensional lattice?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, adiabatic-model

Is there a standard quantum algorithm (adiabatic or density matrix based) that can output the answer to a 2-dimensional closest vector problem:

[image]

ie. find the closest lattice point (the blue one) that is closest to a random point in 2-dimension (the red point)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a polynomial time algorithm for SVP in 2d lattice. With SVP You can solve CVP. Therefor, You can implement it in quantum setting to have a quantum algorithm to solve CVP in 2d

Answer (score 0):

Closest vector in 1 dimensional lattice is a natural adiabatic problem, eg. 3.3 is closest to 3:

[image]

---

On a 2-dimensional lattice span of

$$\vec e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix},\vec e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

The point $$\vec p = \begin{bmatrix}7.7\\ 13.9 \end{bmatrix}$$

is closest to

[image]

requiring prior $N^{dim}$ circuit constructions, probably negating any computational speed advantages.

---

The angle between $e_1, e_2$ can be computed according to

$$ \theta_{e_1e_2} = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{e_1.e_2}{|e_1||e_2|} \right) = 18 ^\circ$$

which is far from orthogonal.

On the other hand, defining $e_3$ to be

$$e_3  = 9 e_1  - 4 e_2 = 9 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} - 4 \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

we obtain

[image]

$$\theta_{e_2e_3} = 93^\circ$$

which is nearly orthogonal (a desirable property).

An arbitrary lattice point defined in terms of $e_1, e_2$ coordinates, eg.

$$[3,2] = 3e_1 + 2e_2$$

can always be reached via a different coordinates in the new basis $e_2, e_3$ since

$$ [3,2] = 3e_1 + 2e_2 = \frac{3}{9}(4e_2 + e_3) + 2e_2 = \frac{10}{3}e_2 +\frac{1}{3}e_3 = \left[\frac{10}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right]$$

The LLL algorithm provides a methodical way of finding a new nearly-orthogonal basis whose set of lattice integer points are transformed in some specific way from those of the original basis.

---

Using original (very non-orthogonal) basis,

$$ a \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 7.7 \\ 13.9 \end{bmatrix}$$

gives the exact real number solution

$$a = 5.45$$
$$b = 0.75$$

Rounding to nearest integer, the approximated nearest lattice coordinate is:

$$[5, 1]$$

which is far wrong from the correct answer $[3,2]$.

Using the better bases $e_2, e_3$,

$$a\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 7.7 \\ 13.9 \end{bmatrix}$$

gives the exact real number solution

$$a = 3.17$$
$$b = 0.61$$

Rounding to nearest $\frac{1}{3}$ integer, the approximated nearest lattice coordinate is:

$$\left[\frac{10}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right]$$

which is still incorrect, but much closer to the correct lattice point $\left[\frac{10}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right]$.

Thus, orthogonal bases makes diophantine rounding more accurate versus non-orthogonal bases.

---

Factoring as closest vector problem on a lattice:

Let

$$N = 100001 \times 100151=10015200151$$

Then

$$\log N = \log p + \log q = \begin{bmatrix} \log p \\ \log q \end{bmatrix}$$

There exist a partition for which the closest lattice point is

$$ [1,1]$$

[image]

---

Quadratic sieve factorization:

Let

$$N = 6549873$$

Then searching upwards from

$$n = \sqrt {6549873} \approx 2560$$

and computing

$$R_n = 2560^2 \mod {6549873} = 3727 $$

We sieve for $R_n$ with entirely small prime factors within the set of

$$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}$$

Very few $R_n$ naturally satisfy this property, but through enough searching, we eventually obtain:

[image]

[image]

which has the additional property of having able to be linearly combined (with only 0 or 1 and no higher coefficients) [1,0,1,1] as:

$$4433^2\times7253^2\times 8866^2 \equiv 2^4 3^0 5^4 7^2 11^2 13^2 17^0$$

Since both sides are square numbers:

$$4433\times7253\times 8866 \pm 2^2 5^2 7^1 11^1 13^2 \equiv 0 \mod{6549873}$$ and so from Euclid's algorithm

[image]

Verifying:

$$\frac{6549873}{33}= 198481$$

---

Lattice factorization:

Let

$$N= 14763$$

Suppose there exist a lattice method to find a square number n slightly over 14763, having only small prime exponents (ie. using low dimensional lattices) from the set:

$$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}$$

[image]

$$2^{12} 17^2 = 2704 \mod{14763}$$
$$(2^6 17^1)^2 = 52^2 \mod{14763}$$
$$ 1088 \pm 52 = 0 \mod{14763}$$

$$gcd (1036,14763) = 259$$
$$gcd (1140,14763) = 57$$

---

Knapsack problem:

Given a salesperson with starting capital 15 and a choice of items:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}  item & profit & cost \\ A & 10 & 2 \\ B & 5 & 3 \\ C & 15 & 5 \\ D & 6 & 6 \\  E & 6 & 1 \\ F & 18 & 4 \\ G & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the optimal items the salesperson should stock in order to maximize the total profit.

[image]

[image]

Despite exponentially growing $2^n$ solution space with respect to the number of item choices, the YES/NO knapsack problem can be solved

$$ O(n \cdot c)$$

where c is the starting capital constraint and n is the number of items.

---

Number field sieve factorization:

Let

$$N=611$$

There exist some integers $i,j,k,l,m,n,o$ such that if

$$ a = i + j \cdot (o^2 \mod{611})$$
$$ b = i + j \cdot \sqrt o$$
$$ c = k + l \cdot (o^2 \mod{611})$$
$$ d = k + l \cdot \sqrt o$$
$$ e = m + n \cdot \sqrt o$$

then

$$abcd = e^2$$

which then implies

$$ gcd(611, ac - e) = \{1, f, 611\}$$

is a factor with high likelihood.

[image]

$$N = 34891 $$

[image]

[image]

[image]

Choose

$$m = 10$$

$$n = 1234$$

$$f = 1 \cdot x^3 + 2 \cdot x^2 + 3 \cdot x + 4$$

Then $r_0 = --1.65062$ is a root of $f$.

Define

$$A(x) = 1 \cdot x^2 + 1 \cdot x + 1$$
$$B(x) = 2 \cdot x^2 + 2 \cdot x + 2$$

Then

$$A(r_0)B(r_0) = 8.60234$$

But then, by polynomial division

$$A(x)B(x) = k(x)f(x) + c(x)$$

$$2x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 2 = (2x)f(x) + (-4x+2)$$

At the special root point $x=r_0$,

$$A(r_0)B(r_0) = (2r_0)(0) + (-4r_0+2) = -4r_0 + 2 = 8.60248$$

---

Sieve of Eratosthenes:

A 1 TB storage disc can store 8,000,000,000,000 bits of pre-checked primality information.

It ascertains primality with 100% accuracy via look-up table method for any $N < 10^{13}$.

For $N > 10^{13}$, if any $gcd(N, p_i) > 1$ then N is composite. If no such result is found, then either N is prime, or N is composite but with all its factors larger than $10^{13}$.

The percentage of integers $\in [10^{13}, \infty]$ which are primes or have exclusively large prime factors $\gt 10^{13}$ likely approaches 0. (?)

Thus this sieve of eratosthenes scheme can ascertain with near 100% certainty if a large random $N > 10^{13}$ is definitely composite or prime/near-prime.

---

Adiabatic factorization:

Let

$$N = 12345$$

and

$$H = 12345^2(12345 - ij)^2 + (i-j)^2 + i$$

[image]

[image]

---

Quantum approximate optimization:

Let

$$ S = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = a |0\rangle + b|1\rangle$$

Define 2-punch operation parametrized by $\{t, \theta\}$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos {\frac{\theta}{2}} & i \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \\ i\sin {\frac{\theta}{2}} &  \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} e^{-it} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{it} \end
{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ = \begin{bmatrix} a e^{-it}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} + i b  e^{it}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \\ i a e^{-it}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} + b e^{it}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Starting with

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{bmatrix}$$

and applying operation $(\frac{3}{8}\pi, \frac{7}{8}\pi)$ repeatedly, the resulting probability distribution of $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ cycles wildly through many stages:

[image]